# Length of uint8_t* const array

Tags: arduino-ide, c, array

I've an array of type uint8_t* const with 6 items, defined like this

```
uint8_t* const neighbourSet[] = {PEER1, PEER2, PEER3, PEER4, PEER5, PEER6};
```

Whereas each element in this array is `static uint8_t` defined like this

```
static uint8_t PEER1[] {0x86, 0xF3, 0xEB, 0x7A, 0xE8, 0x3B};
static uint8_t PEER2[] {0x86, 0xF3, 0xEB, 0x7A, 0xA1, 0x09};
static uint8_t PEER3[] {0x84, 0x0D, 0x8E, 0x03, 0x95, 0xED};
static uint8_t PEER4[] {0x84, 0x0D, 0x8E, 0x03, 0x99, 0xD5};
static uint8_t PEER5[] {0x80, 0x7D, 0x3A, 0xC5, 0x2B, 0x79};
static uint8_t PEER6[] {0x84, 0x0D, 0x8E, 0x03, 0x95, 0x1D};
```

When I do

```
  Serial.print("size:");
  Serial.println(sizeof(neighbourSet));
```

I get `size:24`. I am expecting the size to be 6. could someone explain ? 
I don't want to hardcode the total number of PEER in a separate integer variable. I want my for loop to run through each element till the total size of array.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(neighbourSet); i++) {
         //do something for each PEER. 
         delay(50);
    }
```

Comment: uint8_t* is a pointer. on AVR it is 2 bytes. on 32bit architectures 4 bytes

Comment: you want `const uint8_t* const neighbourSet`?

Comment: Hint: `sizeof()` gives the number of bytes. You are looking for `membersof()`. It is often defined as `#define membersof(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))`.

Comment: `int totalPeers = (sizeof(neighbourSet) / sizeof(neighbourSet[0]));` worked. Thanks Mikael !

Comment: @MikaelPatel you should post that as an answer. I was going to post the same, but then I saw your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sizeof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) gives the number of bytes. You are looking for `membersof()`. It is often defined as:

```
#define membersof(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))
```

And in the example above:

```
for (int i = 0; i < membersof(neighbourSet); i++) {
     //do something for each PEER. 
     delay(50);
}
```

For more practical C/C++ macro and type extensions please see the Cosa [Types.h](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/Types.h#L165) file.

Comment: Sizeof doesn't work for pointers